# Position text on an img-s exact spots and keep them there

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, positioning

I'm in trouble positioning a website. I have a background image and according to it I want some texts that should stay in an exact position of this img. So if the image moves because the resolution is different, the text should move with the img(these gonna be menu items that's why I need them, and they should appear on the tentacles of an octopus).

Also if the positioning of the img and the texts is fixed in css, then on smaller resolutions only a small part of the img appears. Scrolls appear but if I use them only these parts of the img can be seen anyhow.

Help please! :(

I would accept any kind of solution to this, even jquery or javascript, no matter how I have to solve this.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I changed the site a bit: Now I have a background img, and on top of it a div(this is the base). Inside it another image of an octopus. I have menus(texts in divs) that should always stay on the tentacles. So I need the octopus and the menus move together and always be seen(the whole of it on any kind of resolution). The octopus now can be seen all time whole with this width/height:100% settig. I also need to center it but it doesn't work anyhow I try, but it's the smaller problem. The biggest are still the menus that should move with the picture(stay on the picture on the tentacles).

Comment: do you've a jsFiddle created showcasing the problem which you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

you cans use to remove scroll

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: That is not what I want, cause then on small resolutions only a part of the image will appear but i need it all (the whole picture) to be always seen.

Comment: I changed the site a bit:

Now I have a background img, and on top of it a div(this is the base). Inside it another image of an octopus. I have menus(texts in divs) that should always stay on the tentacles. So I need the octopus and the menus move together and always be seen(the whole of it on any kind of resolution). 

The octopus now can be seen all time whole with this width/height:100% settig. I also need to center it but it doesn't work anyhow I try, but it's the smaller problem. The biggest are still the menus that should move with the picture(stay on the picture on the tentacles).

Comment: can you show me any explain image to know what you need or add your  code here,,

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-RSRXUoSOjEZi1nVk1Pc1V1NEk/view?usp=sharing

I can only illustrate it this way. My code is a mess and does not working so it would be useless :/

Answer (score 0):

i hope this to help you ...[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgutaykv/1/)

```
.atag1{
   position:absolute; 
    top:5%;
    left:2%;
}
.atag2{
   position:absolute; 
    top:18%;
    left:5%;
}
.atag3{
   position:absolute; 
    top:30%;
    left:18%;
     color:blue;
}
.atag4{
   position:absolute; 
    top:50%;
    left:60%;
     color:blue;
}



<div id="container" style="background:red;width:500px;height:500px;opacity:1" ui-widget-content> 

  <div style="background:black;width:300px;height:300px;opacity:1" id="wrapper">
      <img id="img" style="width:100%;height:100%" src="http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/2270/2270821/cartoon-and-photoshop-camera-789676-3-s-307x512.jpg">  </img>
       <a class="atag1" >text1</a>
      <a class="atag2" >text2</a>
      <a class="atag3" >text3</a>
      <a class="atag4" >text3</a>

    </div>

    <button  id ="b"  >change image </button>   
</div>


$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#wrapper").draggable({ containment: "parent" });
    $("#b").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").show().animate({ "width": (Math.random() * 360) + 0 }, "slow");
     $("#wrapper").show().animate({ "height": (Math.random() * 360) + 0 }, "slow");
    })



});
```

[image]